# Como criar coluna a partir de dados contidos em outras colunas

Tags: r

Olá, sou novo em R e estou apanhando pra resolver esse problema. Tenho uma planilha que chamei de `base` e possui 2573 observações de 103 variáveis.

[image: A parte da minha planilha que contém as informações que quero extrair tem a seguinte cara]

Eu criei uma coluna auxiliar com o nome de `reclamacoes.titulo`. Preciso checar onde está o 1 em cada linha e retornar, na coluna `reclamacoes.titulo`, ou o nome da coluna correspondente ou o índice dela.
Consegui escrever um código que retorna os índices das linhas onde cada um está. Por exemplo, os índices das linhas que possuem 1 na coluna `periculosidade` é:

```
> dic.busca.indice.periculosidade
[1]   81   84   85   91   92  516  575  576  577  578  579  636  637  638  639  640  641  643  742  743  744  745  746  747  969
[26]  970  971  972 1389 1390 1391 1392 1393 1394 1395 1396 1397 1398 1411 1412 1415 1416 1417 1418 1419 1420 1421 1422 1423 1424
[51] 1425 1426 1531 1532 1533 1534 1535 1694 1695 1979
```

Nesse caso, minha coluna `reclamacoes.titulo` era pra ter a seguinte cara:

```
Justiça Gratuita
Justiça Gratuita
Perdas e Danos
Perdas e Danos
Perdas e Danos
Perdas e Danos
Perdas e Danos
Prescrição
Perdas e Danos
Justiça Gratuita
Perdas e Danos
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A parte mais difícil foi feita. Agora basta escolher os índices presentes em `dic.busca.indice.periculosidade` dentro da coluna `reclamacoes.titulo`. Basta rodar

```
base$reclamacoes.titulo[dic.busca.indice.periculosidade]
```

e o resultado pretendido irá aparecer.

Os colchetes (`[]`) permite que tu busque a i-ésima observação dentro de um vetor do `R`. Por exemplo, `base$reclamacoes.titulo[12]` irá retornar a décima segunda observação dentro de `base$reclamacoes.titulo`.

Answer (score 1):

Peguei apenas as colunas que possuam pelo menos um valor `1` do seu exemplo e também simplifiquei o nome das variáveis para utilizar no meu código.

```
base <- data.frame('Presc' = c(rep(0,7),1,rep(0,3)), 
  'Per_Dan' = c(rep(0,2),rep(1,5),rep(c(0,1),2)), 
  'Just_Grat' = c(rep(1,2),rep(0,7),1,0))
```

Criei a variável `reclamacoes.titulo`

```
base$reclamacoes.titulo <- NA
```

e rodei um `for` para pegar o nome da coluna que possui o valor `1` para cada linha

```
for(i in 1:nrow(base)){
  base$reclamacoes.titulo[i] <- names(base)[which(base[i,] == 1)]
}
```